# No email notifications for updates on my questions

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Although **Follow** is pressed, **email the updates** is ticked, **Email me when there are any new answers** is ticked as well I do not receive any e-mail notifications. Neither for new answers nor comments.

I am using Google account to log in.

Does anyone experience the same?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43160/no-email-notifications-for-updates-on-my-questions/) by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3060 on 2012-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The emails will come to your ROS Account.
On this page, in the top right just below tags you can find that you logged in.
If there is any message for you, then the icon msg icon will change its colour.

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2012-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2012-09-05**:
So I will never get it on email address I specified when tethered Answers account to Google one?

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2012-09-05**:
As per my knowledge ...yes...

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2012-09-05**:
That's kind of useless then... Thanks anyway